# "Cannot read property 'user' of undefined" when trying to create user document at account creation with Firebase

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, jsx

I'm trying to add the user ID at account creation to a new collection called 'accounts' (which will also contain the displayName). However, I keep getting a 'Cannot read property 'user' of undefined' error. What am I doing wrong?

```
// Sign up
           try {
               setError("")
               setLoading(true)
               await signup(emailRef.current.value, passwordRef.current.value)
                   //Set displayname
                   //This part works
                   .then((result) => {
                       return result.user.updateProfile({
                           displayName: displayNameRef.current.value
                       })
                   })
                   //Set user id
                   //"Cannot read property 'user' of undefined" ?
                   .then((result) => {
                       return accounts.doc(result.user.uid).set({
                           userID: result.user.id
                       });
                   });
               history.push("/")
           }
```

Comment: Firstly if you are already using `await` it would be more readable to do something like: `const result = await signup(...)`
Secondly, have you tried printing the result? What do you see?

Comment: I've used console.log on the result and I get undefined. That's odd. Why is it that I can get the newly created user and update the displayname but creating a new document using that same new user wont work?

Comment: I think you may have a syntactical issue, try my suggested syntax and console the result.

Comment: Still getting undefined after using your syntax

Comment: well it's hard to say since I cannot see much of your code, but you are not getting anything from the db which means either it is not saving properly or you are not calling it properly.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/github/Furkan-rgb/photo_db?file=/src/components/Signup.js
Are you able to open this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try inserting this instead of your `try` in `Signup.js`

```
try {
      setError("");
      setLoading(true);
      const result = await signup(
        emailRef.current.value,
        passwordRef.current.value
      );
      //Set displayname
      //https://medium.com/@doyinolarewaju/firebase-adding-extra-information-to-user-on-sign-up-and-other-tips-4ebe215866e
      await result.user.updateProfile({
        displayName: displayNameRef.current.value
      });

      console.log(result);

      //Set user id
      await accounts.doc(result.user.uid).set({
        userID: result.user.id
      });
      history.push("/");
    }
```

Comment: This is what I get: Function DocumentReference.set() called with invalid data. Unsupported field value: undefined (found in field userID in document accounts/gw0YZ3dLxjdjiQSkdHkGrTPmvIC2)

Comment: what is in the `result` in the console?

Comment: Found the problem. Had to change `userID: result.user.id,` to `userID: result.user.uid,`. Thank you so much for your help, Michael.